# How to measure contention in lock-free compare-and-swap loops on Linux?

Tags: concurrency, profiling, lock-free

Suppose we have insert a node into a list in a simple lock-free manner. Assume we are recycling nodes from an object pool so that we don't have to use hazard pointers and such. `cas_failure` does things like use pause instructions or system calls like `sched_yield` (which is of course inappropriate for code that needs to be truely lock-free instead of just fast.)

```
 void cas_failure(void);
 void cas_success(void);

 struct node;

 struct aba {
    struct node *contents;
    uint32_t tag;
 };

 typedef _Atomic(struct aba) atomic_node;

 struct node {
    int head;
    struct node * tail;
 };

 atomic_node list_head;

 void insert(struct node *new_nodep)
 {
    for (;;) {
        struct aba head = atomic_load(&list_head);
        new_nodep->tail = head;
        if (atomic_compare_exchange(&list_head, head,
                        (struct aba){head.tag + 1U, new_nodep})) {
            break;
        }
        cas_failure();
    }
 }
```

How can I use a performance profiling tool to monitor the amount of contention in such loops?

Is it maybe possible to call a function send an event to Linux's perf in `cas_failure`?

Comment: What about defining some kind of tracepoint in your code (in contention path), for example uprobe: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/uprobetracer.txt http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-06-28/linux-ftrace-uprobe.html https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/examples/uprobe_example.txt https://lwn.net/Articles/499190/ or "user-level statically defined tracing (USDT)" probes http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-07-03/hacking-linux-usdt-ftrace.html. They will be nop when not in use and can be replaced with `perf` to actual event generation for using in `perf record`.